# What free software can I use to create a 3D diagram like this?

Tags: windows, linux

The diagram I would like to create is almost identical to this. 
[image]

I'd like to recreate that exact effect of the blocks stacking. 
Linux software is preferred, but windows is fine as well. I don't have access to any other OS.

Comment: Note that your diagram is not 3D it is 2D with a 3D effect. For the above diagram you don't need the complication of 3D software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MS-Office Powerpoint,  or Libreoffice Impress.

In there you'll find some palettes called "Standard shapes" and "Insert basic Shapes"" (I don't recall the exact palette names) . You can drag and drop the cubes from the palette into your slide. Multiply them by copy-and-paste, arrange them with "equal space", "align to bottom" GUI commands. Put text inside the cube symbols by choosing "Add text...", it should have appropriate size and  be centered.

Then you can export the slide in a difffernt image format.

Comment: The cube under the basic shapes menu for LibreOffice is exactly what I was searching for. I've managed to create exactly what I want, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Several ways of doing it...

First, you could create a static image using the GIMP or any other image editor.  I'd bet that this is how your sample image got created. To do it, you'd first draw a single block.  Then clone it and place the copies to create a single layer of the 3d cube grid.  Select all of that, copy and paste it as a new layer, move it down and to the left a tad.  Then paste again as another new layer, and scoot it further down and further left.

You could also create it programmatically, after building images of certain base items like the boxes.  Create a new image, create a pointer to a template image of the box, add a copy of the template image at X/Y coords, repeat.  I could do it in PHP or Java w/o issues, and some studying of classes/methods/functions/libraries available could do it in C, C++, or C#.

Comment: Probably easier in LibreOffice.